# Help with Ros Noetic installation on Manjaro. libtinyxml2 issue when trying to access or install packages

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, tinyxml

I am getting the error:
rospack: error while loading shared libraries: libtinyxml2.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have manually installed tinyxml2, thinking that would work, using:
paru -S tinyxml2

I am completely new to ROS, and am going through the tutorials. I encounter the error
when trying to use rospack find, and then when trying to use rosrun to run any packages.